# Is the following counterexample valid?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm being asked to verify if the following statement is true or false.

Let $W$ $\subseteq M_{5,5}(\mathbb{R})$ such that Rank($A$) = 3 for $A \in W$. True / False: W is a subspace of $M_{5,5}$

I'm not sure what $\mathbb{R}'s$ presence denotes, but I assume it is to clarify that $M_{5,5}$ is the set of 5x5 matrices composed of real number entries.

The book I am learning with (Ron Larson's *Elementary Linear Algebra 8e*) denotes 2 constraints that must be valid for some subset to be a subspace of a vector space. Let ***W*** be a potential subspace of some vector space ***V***.

1. $W$ is closed under vector addition $\implies W_1+W_2 \in W$
2. $W$ is closed under scalar multiplication $\implies$ c $\in$$\mathbb{R}$ $\implies cW \in W$

I claimed that the statement was false, $W$ is not a subset of $M_{5,5}$ because it fails property 1: closure under vector addition. To prove this I provided the following counter-example:

Let $W_1$ = $$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
$W_2$= $$\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

The rank of $W_1,W_2$ is 3 as they each have 3 linearly independent vectors. So $W_1,W_2 \in W$. It follows that if $W$ is a subspace then the statement ($W_1+W_2$)$\in W$ must hold.

$W_1+W_2 \implies$ $$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

But ($W_1+W_2$) $\notin W$ because it is composed of 4 linearly independent vectors, $R_2,R_3,R_4,R_5$ and $R_1$ is a linear combination of the vectors in $R_3$ and $R_4$ $\implies$ rank($W_1+W_2$) = 4 $\ne$3

$\therefore$ $W$ is not a subspace of $M_{5,5}$ because it is not closed under vector addition.

Does this counterexample hold up, or did I do something in there that makes it unsound? I am also sure that if I am right, there is surely a more trivial counterexample, but this is all I could think of.

Finally this proof was for an undergraduate linear algebra course where students are not expected to have formal proof writing knowledge, so please don't judge the rigor of my proof by the conventions a traditional proof-based class would have.

Comment: $0_{5\times 5}$ is not of rank 3 . and for trivial counter example ,Rank of $W$ and rank of $-W$ are same . $W+(-W)=0_{5\times 5}$.

Comment: What do you even mean by the rank of a subset of $M_{5,5}(\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: @DanielSchepler I mean that W is a subset of the set of all 5x5 matrices composed of real numbers. And that all matrices in W must have a rank of 3, meaning they are not just 5x5 matrices composed of real numbers, but they also must have no more or less than 3 linearly independent rows (a rank of 3). I don't really know what you're asking so I'm sorry if this doesn't clarify anything.

Comment: @MeetPatel thank you for the response, as I expected there is clearly a more trivial counter example than the one I came up with. But is my original one still correct, just more convoluted?

Comment: My confusion was that usually, rank is defined on individual matrices, not on sets of matrices.  It would have been clearer to say something like: $W \subseteq M_{5,5}(\mathbb{R})$ is such that $\operatorname{rank}(M) = 3$ for each $M \in W$.  (The way you put it would be similar to saying: $S \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ is even.)

Comment: @MattKuehr Your example is correct.

Comment: In your proposed counterexample, it's not clear exactly what subset you are using for $W$.  For example, without specifying what $W$ is, it's not clear why you believe you must have $W_1 \in W$ and $W_2 \in W$.

Comment: Unless what you *really* wanted to say is that in the problem, $W$ is *defined* to be the set of *all* $5\times 5$ real matrices which have rank 3.

Comment: @DanielSchepler thank you for the insight! I've yet to take a formal proof writing class so I often struggle to articulate what I'm trying to say in a way that's proper on here. I see now why my phrasing leads to confusion.